# horizontally scrolling table : multiple fixed columns

Tags: html, css

I was trying to make a horizontally scrolling table and I was able to make it but only the first column is fixed. I need to make the scrolling table for two or more column to be fixed.

Here is the link of the fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jeewanaryal/8eavy9eo/)

I want to make this table scrolling for two or more than 2 columns be fixed and rest scrolling. Is it possible to make a CSS class (example "fixedColumn") so that any column having this CSS class is fixed and rest of the columns are scrolling? I can not use any JavaScript plugins (no JS at all).

Please help.

**HTML**

```
<div class="table-wrapper">
    <table id="consumption-data" class="data">
        <thead class="header">
            <tr>
                <th>Month</th>
                <th>Item 1</th>
                <th>Item 2</th>
                <th>Item 3</th>
                <th>Item 4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="results">
            <tr>
                <th>Jan</th>
                <td>3163</td>
                <td>3163</td>
                <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Feb</th>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Mar</th>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Apr</th>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>  
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <th>May</th>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Jun</th>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>...</th>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.table-wrapper { 
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:visible;
    width:250px;
    margin-left: 120px;
```

}

```
td, th {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    width: 100px;
}

th:first-child {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as long as your table has a fixed width, you can do something like this:

```
td:nth-child(3) {
    position: fixed;
    left: 160px;
    width:100px;
}
```

of course you'll need to adjust both `left` and `width` properties, and the nth-child according to the column you want to keep in a fixed position, but you'll get the idea. This being said, I'd try using divs instead of tables, it's far more manageable for instances like this

Comment: I am trying to use a simple CSS class name to fixed any columns and not using the nth-child selector. Is it possible ?

Comment: yes, and it's even better, just give a class to the TD element (and also the TH as we're at it) and get rid of the nth-child.

Comment: I tried it all but it's not working :-( ... can you please try in that fiddle?

Comment: Hi Fabio, its looks working but I have two issues. First, if I have long string, it overlaps the other column data and second is the fixed column does not hide the scrolling column data. Can you please check this updated fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/jeewanaryal/zxde4a4f/1/

Comment: well, of course you'll need to adjust it, I'm telling you an option based on your code, personally I wouldn't even use a table and I don't know why you need the fixed column behavior, so I did it based on your description and your existing code. For the "hide", simply add this:  `background:#ccc; z-index:100;`